# Less clunky way of creating a responsive web header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I've currently got a website header that functions fine on a desktop. I had initially planned to stack the content so that the pages would then display under the logo. I have seen hamburger menus used for a drop-down which is what I'd ultimately like to achieve, retaining the logo on the left.

I know this will likely take time but I think I'm almost there. I just think it'd be easier to have the same elements be responsive rather than creating two separate headers and toggling visibility.

So currently I have this:

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}


.mobile-header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.mobile-logo-container {
float: left;
width: 60%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.mobile-navigation-container {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.mobile-logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 60vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:2vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.header {
visibility: hidden;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.header-container {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo-container {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.navigation-container {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 }

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.mobileheader {
visibility: visible;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.mobile-header-container {
 visibility: visible;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.mobile-logo-container {
 visibility: visible;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.mobile-navigation-container {
 visibility: visible;
 }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
.mobile-logo {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 }

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-header">
<div class="mobile-header-container">
<div class="mobile-logo-container">
<img class="mobile-logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="mobile-navigation-container space-evenly">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="headerfill">
</div>
```

This looks fine, and is suitable for desktop use. I just need them to be responsive in a way when on mobile the elements adjust.

[image: Example of how the final navigation would look]
The icons don't have to switch and I know that can be done with event listeners if needed. Just not sure how to have the original elements format differently on mobile devices without creating two separate headers.

Hopefully the image gives a good enough idea of what I'm aiming for. First time I've tried to attempt this sort of drop-down navigation so thanks in advance :)

```
UPDATE
```

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet3.1.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. I need to find a way to incorporate that design (using the code I already have) with the answer from @Nyan. I've removed the media queries and the separate mobile and desktop headers. Can't figure this out.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
document.querySelector('button')
 .addEventListener('click', e => {
   menu.classList.toggle('active')
  })
```

```css
header{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
}
nav a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
button{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {  
  nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active{
    display: block;
  }
  button{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
  <button>menu</button>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Page1</a>
    <a href="">Page2</a>
    <a href="">Page3</a>
    <a href="">Page4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

It'd run like that, with that structure but retain the initial design. (image above)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting desktop display for responsive site navigation with topnav and event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805153/adjusting-desktop-display-for-responsive-site-navigation-with-topnav-and-event-l)

Comment: This question was first so it'd be the other way around. They're based on the same code but both ask different specifics so it's easier to find a solution related to a different issue. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create just button, which is hidden on big screens and visible on small, and listen click event on it. Or if you don't want to create new elements at all, you can use `::after` and `::before`, and listen them.

Listener can, for example, toggle class `active` on list.

List itself can be absolutely positioned to bottom of header, and hidden when doesn't have `active` class.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
document.querySelector('button')
 .addEventListener('click', e => {
   menu.classList.toggle('active')
  })
```

```css
header{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
}
nav a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
button{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {  
  nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active{
    display: block;
  }
  button{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
  <button>menu</button>
  <nav>
    <a href="">one</a>
    <a href="">two</a>
    <a href="">three</a>
    <a href="">four</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Which one of this steps cause you more questions?

Comment: To be completely honest, @Nyan. I don't fully understand what you mean. I could use this but I'd decided to have the desktop layout remain the same and the mobile to have the drop-down using the same navigation text rather than having two copies and hiding based on device size.

Comment: I mean you can hide you current `navigation-container` element on mobile with media queries, and show it only when it has `active` class, like `.navigation-container {display: none}.navigation-container.active {display: block}`

Comment: I understand that. I just don't know how that'd assist with creating a drop-down when menu elements would be the same.

Comment: guess I should show it by code example
https://jsfiddle.net/duo2mgkc/8/

Comment: Please add relevant code in the answer or make it a comment. This isn't going to answer the OP

Comment: That's sort of what I'm going for, yeah. Just need to figure out a way of making that work with the existing design I have @Nyan

Comment: I've updated the question @SuperDJ, just need that concept to be implemented with my pre-existing design