# Adjusting desktop display for responsive site navigation with topnav and event listeners

Tags: javascript, css

I've been working on this for almost the entire day. I'm almost there. Just need the finishing touches that I don't know how to implement.

My navigation should look like this:
[image: Example of navigation]
This is how the desktop version should look:

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, all page titles are horizontal and evenly spaced.

I now have this code:

```css
body,
html {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0vw;
  margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
  height: 10vh;
  border: none;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navigation-container {
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    //justify-content: space-evenly; 
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .space-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  nav.active {
    display: block;
  }
}

.logo {
  height: 8vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  padding-left: 4vh;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
}

img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  line-height: 1em;
  object-fit: contain;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .nav {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    object-fit: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.nav:hover {
  color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: 4vh;
  padding-right: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
  line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}

button {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active {
    display: inline;
  }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Website Header</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
          <button>☰</button>
          <nav>
            <p class="nav">Page1</p>
            <p class="nav">Page2</p>
            <p class="nav">Page3</p>
            <p class="nav">Page4</p>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script>
    let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
    document.querySelector('button')
      .addEventListener('click', e => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
      })
  </script>
```

The button now appears and is functional on mobile.

Fixes:

1) Show the page names horizontally on desktop.

2) Allow the button to toggle between `☰` and `✘`
May be able to implement using: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` just now sure how to though.

3) Format the drop-down so that the text is within its own box on top of the page and right aligned.

I've reached a dead end. I'm just not sure how to fully make this work. Any suggestions may help. You can also edit my code as an answer to get it fully functional if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

```
Update 1
```

```js
menu = document.querySelector('nav');
    document.querySelector('i')
        .addEventListener('click', e => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
    document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-bars')
    document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-times')
    })
```

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 2vh;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}


    nav{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: right;
    }
    nav a{
        display:block;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
        font-size: 2vw;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        color: #000000;
        padding-left: auto;
        padding-right: auto;
        line-height: 1em;
        object-fit: contain;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    i{
        display: none !important;
    }
 
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        nav{
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;

            display: none;

            font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
            font-size: 2.5vw;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            color: #000000;
            padding-left: auto;
            padding-right: auto;
            line-height: 1em;
            object-fit: contain;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        nav.active{
            display: block;
        }
        i{
            display: block!important;
            margin:5px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<nav>
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</nav>
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

I'm most of the way there now. I've got the switching icons and most of the functionality. There's just a slight issue with text size when resizing the browser window.

Comment: If anyone is paying you to do this, use http://getbootstrap.com/.

Comment: Nope, just trying to teach myself for now. @user2182349. I've almost got the menu working. I'll worry about animation after it becomes functional.

Comment: So 'Fixes' refers to what needs to be fixed?

Comment: @user2182349 I've got most of them now, down to a single issue with text size but I think it's an issue with redundancy. See `Update 1` on the post :)

Comment: @helpmeplease , Try my code. It works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple responsive website header based on existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804011/simple-responsive-website-header-based-on-existing-code)

Answer (score 1):

```css
    body, html {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 0vw;
        margin: 0vw;
    }
    
    .header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    height: 10vh;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid;
    }
    
    .headerfill {
    height: 10vh;
    border: none;
    }
    
    .header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .logo-container {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: left;
    }
    
    .navigation-container {
      width: 60%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      //justify-content: space-evenly; 
      margin: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .space-evenly {
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .logo {
    height:8vh;
    max-width: 80vw; 
    padding-top:1vh;
    padding-bottom:1vh;
    padding-left:4vh;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    }
    
    img{
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    }
    
    .nav {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    object-fit: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    object-fit: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    }
    
    .nav:hover {
    color: #096e67;
    }
    
    a:link {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 4vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    }
    }
    
    
    
    button {
      display: none;
    }
    
    nav {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      nav {
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        padding:10px;
        display: none;
      }
      nav.active {
        display: inline;
      }
      button {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -27px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
      }
      button:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f0c9";
      }
      .header-container {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
      }
      .logo-container, .navigation-container {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .navigation-container {
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 10px;
        position:relative;
      }
      .navigation-container.active {
        
      }
      .navigation-container.active button:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f00d";
      }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Website Header</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo-container">
    <img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
      <button></button>
      <nav>
        <p class="nav">Page1</p>
        <p class="nav">Page2</p>
        <p class="nav">Page3</p>
        <p class="nav">Page4</p>
      </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
      <script>
          let container = document.querySelector('.navigation-container');
        let menu = document.querySelector('nav');
        document.querySelector('button')
          .addEventListener('click', e => {
            menu.classList.toggle('active');
             container.classList.toggle('active')
          })
      </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/1cdu745t/39/

This works for you. I have added new styles for mobile and updated layout.
Try my code. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I've opted against using buttons and went with http://fontawesome.io instead :)

Comment: @helpmeplease, It's my pleasure.

Comment: @helpmeplease, If answer is correct, please close the question. Thanks.